# Find the number present in a line inside a document if there is a string match from a list of strings

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching

I have a list of strings. If any word in the list matches inside a line within a document,
I want to get as output the matching word and a number which will be present in the line, mostly after that matching word. The word and number is mostly separated by a `space` or `:`

Example from document:

```
Expedien: 1-21-212-16-26
```

My list:

```
my_list = ['Reference', 'Ref.', 'tramite', 'Expedien']
```

The numbers inside the line for the matching string can be either separated by `-` or maybe without.
Example: `1-21-22-45` or `RE9833`

In this case `RE9833` should come entirely (not only the number) if a matching word from the list is found inside the line.

How to write a regex in python for this.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input file:**

```
$cat input_file
Expedien: 1-21-212-16-26 #other garbage
Reference RE9833 #tralala
abc
123
456
Ref.: UV1234
tramite  1234567
Ref.:
```

**Sample:**

```
import re

my_list = ['Reference', 'Ref.', 'tramite', 'Expedien']

#open the file as input
with open('input_file','r') as infile:
  #create an empty dict to store the pairs
  #that we will extract from the file
  res = dict()
  #for each input line
  for line in infile:
    #the only place we will use regex in this code
    #we split the input strings in a list of strings using
    #as separator : if present followed by some spaces
    elems = re.split('(?::)?\s+', line)
    #we test that we have at least 2 elements 
    #if not we continue with the following line
    if len(elems) >= 2 :
      contains = False
      #tmp will store all the keys identfied
      tmp = ''
      #we go through all the strings present in this list of strings
      for elem in elems:
        #when we enter this if we have already found the key and we have the value
        #at this iteration
        if contains:
          #we store it in the dict
          #reset the check and leave this loop
          res.update({tmp : elem})
          contains = False
          break
        #we check if the elem is in my_list
        if elem in my_list:
          #if this is the case
          #we set contains to true and we save the key in tmp
          contains = True
          tmp = elem
  print(res)
```

**output:**

```
python find_list.py
{'tramite': '1234567', 'Reference': 'RE9833', 'Expedien': '1-21-212-16-26', 'Ref.': ''}
```

**Regex demo:** https://regex101.com/r/kSmLzW/3/

Comment: Thanks Allan. Can you give a brief on why you used the flag and can it be done without using one

Comment: @checkmate: the flag? which one?

Comment: contains = False. That part

Comment: @checkmate: I have to use a if on this flag to branch the behavior of the `for`, and create a different behavior when at the previous iteration we have found an element of your list. If this the case, at the current iteration we know that we will receive the value and we need to store the value and the key in the dict.

Comment: I am getting a lot of junk data when I run this on a directory. I only wanted numbers as output for this. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: @checkmate: is there anything else on the lines you want to analyze? Is the pattern you have described always located at the begining of the lines?

Comment: No it's not always located at the beginning. It might also be there in the middle sometimes. For example a pattern like "Expedien N° 18-0022995" is not getting captured whereas a pattern like "Expedien N°1-0047-00020-00194-02-4" is rightly captured